# Is it safe to delete any partition from SSD?

Tags: partitioning

I have previously installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my SSD, but would like to remove it and install Windows 7 instead. While installing Windows 7 from USB I was given the option to delete, format and extend partitions. Some were listed as "support" (the large portion, ~230gb, and a smaller bit, ~7gb) and one was listed as "system" (~500mb). I'm wondering if it's safe to delete the "system" partition (i.e., does this partition belong to Ubuntu or is it the hardware's?). Noob alert...

Comment: If your going to delete the current OS you can delete every partition if you don't care about the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have Ubuntu on that drive, and no other partitions with files that you might want to keep, it is completely safe to delete everything.

Windows 7 installation will create all the needed partitions it needs to function.

Those partitions you have might have been created automatically by Ubuntu, examples like Boot or Swap partitions, or from a previous Windows installation.

Comment: Ah okay, great. So what is the significance of the "system" specification? And as a follow-up, does deleting all of the partitions pertaining to ubuntu completely purge ubuntu from my drive?

Comment: The "system" partition usually contains boot files for windows 7 installations. Deleting the partitions will not wipe the files of the drive, but you will not be able to access them directly anymore. The windows installation will overwrite the files, and all the space previously occupied by ubuntu will be available